# Print the count of element in a column in table format

Tags: pandas

Given this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"Name":["A","A","B"]})
```

I want to print the count of element in `Name` column in table format as follows:

[image: nd]

This is what I am doing right now:

```
df['Name'].value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Name','Name':'Count'})
```

Though it works, is there a simpler (shorter way) to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df['Name'].value_counts().rename_axis('Name').reset_index(name='Count')
#or df.groupby('Name')['Name'].count().rename('Count').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame({"Count": df.groupby("Name").size()})

     Count
Name    
A     2
B     1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do `agg`

```
df.groupby('Name').agg(Count=('Name','count')).reset_index()
Out[585]: 
  Name  Count
0    A      2
1    B      1
```

Comment: Thanks Yoben, I don't see `agg` definition with `Col_New=('Col',<func>)` in this page https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html, is there a better reference I can find this definition?